# How to add header when piping JPEG image content from axios.get() response

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am using building a node express HTTP web service that calls a web service that returns a JPEG file.  The web service works to proxy the JPEG file but I need to add some content headers to the returned GET request that I respond via pipe.  Any suggestions?

```
app.get('/rendition', function (req, res){

    let uri = `https://example.com/thumbnail2x`;

    axios.get(uri).then(function(response){
        // how do I add a header here?
        response.data.pipe(res);
    });
})
```

Comment: Does the usual `res.header()`/`.set`/`.setHeader` just before `.pipe()` not work? Additionally, you *might* need to pass `responseType: 'stream'` to axios to pipe the response like that, but if it works already, great!

Comment: @cbr Setting the custom headers before the pipe does work. But shouldn't axios handle this on its own without a work around?